# Analysis and categories

Tags: category-theory

Can the concept of topology be generalized to deal with categories instead of sets such that one can define continuous mappings between categories possibly using categories with countably or uncountably infinite set of objects and morphisms ?

Answer (score 3):

It is not very clear what you mean so I hope the following answer, according to two possible interpretations of what you mean, is along what you have in mind. The notion of metric space (which is related to topology) naturally generalized to categories. The terminology is 'weighted category'. Basically, a weighted category is a category in which every arrow is assigned a non-negative real number (possibly $\infty $) in such a way that identities are assigned $0$, and the assignment in sub-additive with respect to composition. Grandis has some papers with things related to weighted categories, in particular in relation to the fundamental category of directed spaces.

A different answer is provided by what are known as Grothendieck topologies and sites. This is a bit more technical so I'll refer you to [this link on the nLab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+topology) for more information.

Comment: Yes , I wawnt to know if it's possible to define metric spaces on categories , define measures and do calculus operations on categories instead of sets.

Comment: I suggest you start then by reading Lawvere's paper "Metric spaces, generalized logic, and closed categories" available in the reprints section of TAC. At the same time you can look at Grandis' papers on the fundamental category of a directed topological space. Quantaloid enriched categories (e.g., Stubbe's work) is also relevant).

Comment: Surely you should at least mention that the standard notion of "continuous functor" is one that preserves limits (in the sense of ordinary category theory)? Or perhaps that there are also internal categories in $\textbf{Top}$ as well as categories enriched in $\textbf{Top}$?

Comment: @ZhenLin I'm not sure these notions relate to what OP wanted. The "continuous" in "continuous functor" has nothing to do with any metric or topological notion. Categories enriched in/internal to Top are more relevant to homotopy theory. But please, I'll interested to hear your opinion about how else the question can be interpreted, perhaps by adding your own answer.